# Converting an int into a python List

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

How do I convert an int into a list of its digits for eg.

> a = 1234

I have to use it as

> [1,2,3,4]

I have tried using

> list(a)

But it shows an error.Anything else that I could use

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am just trying to loop over a integers as for i in range(1,1000): and then use those individual digits to calculate somethings

Answer (score 8):

You can convert `a` to a string first:

```
In [106]: map(int, str(a)) #in python3, you need list(map(int, str(a)))
Out[106]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or use list comprehension instead of `map`:

```
In [108]: [int(digit) for digit in str(a)]
Out[108]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or a manual approach:

```
In [10]: def bar(num):
    ...:     res=[]
    ...:     while num>0:
    ...:         res.append(num%10)
    ...:         num//=10
    ...:     return res[::-1]

In [11]: bar(1234567890)
Out[11]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

All the three ways runs equally in time:

```
In [24]: def foo(num):
    ...:     return list(map(int, str(num)))

In [25]: def bar(num):
    ...:     res=[]
    ...:     while num>0:
    ...:         res.append(num%10)  #or try divmod(n, 10) if you like builtins
    ...:         num//=10
    ...:     return res[::-1]

In [26]: def lstcomp(num):
    ...:     return [int(digit) for digit in str(num)]

In [27]: num=1234567890123456789012345678901234567890

In [28]: timeit foo(num)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 µs per loop

In [29]: timeit bar(num)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.7 µs per loop

In [30]: timeit lstcomp(num)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.6 µs per loop
```

### EDIT:

You can also generate a tuple represented "linked list" as @J.F.Sebastian mentioned:

```
In [523]: f = lambda n, ll=None: f(n//10, (n%10, ll)) if n else ll

In [524]: f(123)
Out[524]: (1, (2, (3, None)))
```

which could be converted to an ordinary list in `O(n)` time:

```
In [537]: llst=f(123)
     ...: res=[]
     ...: while llst:
     ...:     res.append(llst[0])
     ...:     llst=llst[1]
     ...: print res
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I have use that already I just wanted to know that is there anything directly that I could use as it is in python that ints are not iterable but strings are so any other that that could change this format directly

Comment: @saurabh I don't think there is one builtin method doing this, since as you mentioned an int is not an iterable. You can make it a function if you want to reuse it.

Comment: More traditional *functional* approach avoids a mutable state e.g., `f = lambda n, ll=None: f(n//10, (n%10, ll)) if n else ll` btw, `map(int, str(a))` is more functional than `bar()`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `f(12)` returns `(1, (2, None))` with your demo

Comment: @zhangxaochen: it is an expected result (a linked list represented using tuples). It could be converted to an ordinary Python list in `O(n)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian edited in my answer ;)